# Delphi Twebbrowser Validar Recaptcha

Tags: delphi, recaptcha

estou acessando um site para buscar algumas informações, estou usando o delphi com o componente twebbrower, porém tem uma validação com o recaptcha, alguém sabe me dizer como posso validar o recaptcha via programação?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: sou programador faz bastante tempo, mas nesse caso não sei por onde começar

Answer (score 0):

A função do reCAPTCHA/CAPTCHA é exatamente essa. Impedir que a validação/acesso seja feito via programação.

CAPTCHA é uma das medidas para proteger áreas restritas, formulários e outras coisas de bots/robôs que tentam fazer o acesso, validação ou envio de informações.

Imagine um cadastro de usuário ou alguma pesquisa com campos básicos (Data início e fim, CPF e etc), 99% desses casos são recursos que podem ser acessados por qualquer um que faça uma requisição GET.

Sem a proteção de um CAPTCHA, seria "fácil" para qualquer "hacker" construir um bot que fique fazendo requisição GET, preenchendo os dados e submetendo as informações.

Dependendo da quantidade de bots que foi programado, pode haver um gargalho imenso de requisições sendo feitas e informações sendo gravadas no banco de dados. Causando uma grave sobrecarga nos servidores e de dados gravados no banco.

O melhor caminho é verificar se o serviço que está fazendo a pesquisa, fornece algum tipo de API ou WebService para desenvolvedores fazerem a consulta.

Se não existir nenhum tipo de API/WebService, porque não mostra e peça para o usuário preencher só CAPTCHA ou até mesmo todo o site dentro do seu sistema?

Fora isso, é tentar "burlar" a validação, fazendo parse/análise do HTML e possíveis imagens do CAPTCHA (Processamento de imagens), ou tentar achar algum componente/lib de alguém que já tenha feito isso. O que é algo que eu não recomendo nenhum pouco, porque além de estar quebrando uma regra de segurança do serviço, o trabalho e a complexidade vão ser grandes.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente existem serviços que fornecem a solução do captcha, normalmente cobram por cada solução.

Se você inspecionar a página vai ver que logo abaixo do reCaptcha existe uma tag chamada `<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" ...>`. Nela é possível retornar essa solução fornecida pela API que resolve o Captcha, ou seja, basta enviar os dados do captcha para a API, receber a solução e adicionar neste campo, então é só avançar na página.

Um exemplo de um serviço é o [Anti-Captcha](https://anti-captcha.com). No site deste serviço você pode encontrar exemplos de como obter o captcha e fazer as requisições.